# Version support for deep link in iOS and android

Tags: javascript, android, ios, deep-linking

My typical and very easy requirement is to open myapp from within JavaScript, which run on browser obviously.

The concept relatively called "deep linking".

Simplest way for both OS is like this:

window.open('myapp://');

And it works fine.

But I want to know from which versions the applications support deep linking in this way?

As it may happen that some very old kind of people using old version of android system or iOS system and it may not work because there was no concept of deep linking.

Please provide information about it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I can tell you on Android this is supported from the beginning http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element.html

If you look at the bottom the page it mentions it.

I am not 100% sure about iOS but from the documentation I think it is from iOS2

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006786-CH3-SW70

Comment: I see. So for android it has wider support as it was introduced since Android api level 1. Do you have any idea about iOS? Sorry to trouble you, I'm not mobile app developer so I am totally unaware of that.

Comment: @Jaydeep if you find a device running iOS 1, put it in a museum! I don't think I've *ever* seen one. URL scheme deep linking by itself not ideal because anyone without the app installed will get an ugly "Cannot Open Page" error. [Universal Links](https://blog.branch.io/ios-9.2-redirection-update-uri-scheme-and-universal-links) (iOS 9+) and [App Links](https://blog.branch.io/technical-guide-to-deep-linking-android-app-links) (Android M+) are two newer options you might also want to investigate.

Comment: @Alex you're right, man. I don't need to support iOS1 at all. I have to give support from iOS7. And thanks so much for providing very useful info about deep linking, for especially iOS.

Comment: @jaydeep you're welcome! The [Branch.io](https://branch.io) platform where those blog posts came from may be a good option...it'll handle a lot of those edge cases for you automatically